# glsl update an specific row of a 2D texture

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, textures

I am working with "render to texture" feature using FBOs and textures attached.

My problem is that in the fragment shader i don't know how to write to an specific row of the 2D-texture. I do have the information of which row (indicated by a uniform float variable), but i dont know how to draw just there.

Is this possible? Or what is a good way to know where am i in the fragment shader?

My global idea is to render the evolution of a 1D-texture into a 2D-texture from top to bottom. Each evolution step is computed by a fragment shader (usiong render to texture ping-pong method, with 2 FBOs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `discard;` in the fragment shader to throw away fragments you don't want.  Something like

```
if (gl_FragCoord.y != row_to_keep)
    discard;
```

Then render your scene normally, and you'll end up with just one row of the output written.

Answer (score 1):

I think the fragment shader is not the place for this.

If you only want to write into a single line of the FBO, can't you set the vertices of your draw call to only overlap the pixels you want to draw?

Comment: im not sure what you mean. Keep moving a small rectangle while drawing each evolution step?

Comment: If you have a 1-pixel high 1D texture that you want to draw to the framebuffer, generate a 1-pixel high, fullscreen width quad, translate it to the height of the row you want to draw, and draw. Then it will only execute the fragment shader on the pixels in that row.

Comment: I understand. Additionally i need to draw the older states in the older rows too, this is something that keeps acumulating. Let me answer this last part: If i remove the glClear instruction i could end up with a frame that accumulates at each render pass right? If this is true i think your idea solves the problem.

Comment: I think instead i need an accumulation buffer